How can I remove the blue underline in my Readme.md file>
I want to create a skills section in my GitHub README to showcase my abilities. I want each skill icon to be clickable and have a dotted underline. Here’s what it looks like:
Github Readme Skills section
I tried using HTML and CSS to achieve this, but I'm facing issues with the alignment and display of the icons. Here's the code I used:
tried this code


<h3 align="left">Skills</h3>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/html"> 
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=html" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS"> 
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=css" /> 
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript"> 
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=js" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-   side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=react" />
</a>  
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Node.js">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=nodejs" /> 
</a> 
<a href="https://www.mongodb.com/docs/">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=mongodb" />
</a>
 <a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=express" />
</a>
<a href="https://github.com/dancarlton"> 
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=github" />
</a>
<a href="https://www.figma.com/developers/api"> 
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=figma" /> 
</a>   
<a href="https://www.ableton.com/en/"> 
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=ableton" /> 
</a> 



I also tried adding CSS styles to remove the blue underscore and to ensure the icons display inline, but it didn't work as expected:
and adding css


<h3 align="left">Skills</h3>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/html" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=html" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=css" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=js" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=react" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Node.js" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=nodejs" />
</a>
<a href="https://www.mongodb.com/docs/" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=mongodb" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=express" />
</a>
<a href="https://github.com/dancarlton" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=github" />
</a>
<a href="https://www.figma.com/developers/api" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=figma" />
</a> 
<a href="https://www.ableton.com/en/" style="text-decoration: none;">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=ableton" />
</a>  



Can someone help me fix this?

You can apply CSS to the anchor tag(a) to remove the underline. like this: a { text-decoration: none;}


a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
<h3 align="left">Skills</h3>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/html">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=html" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=css" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=js" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Tools_and_testing/Client-side_JavaScript_frameworks/React_getting_started">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=react" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Node.js">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=nodejs" />
</a>
<a href="https://www.mongodb.com/docs/">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=mongodb" />
</a>
<a href="https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Express_Nodejs/Introduction">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=express" />
</a>
<a href="https://github.com/dancarlton">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=github" />
</a>
<a href="https://www.figma.com/developers/api">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=figma" />
</a> 
<a href="https://www.ableton.com/en/">
  <img src="https://skillicons.dev/icons?i=ableton" />
</a>



